# Z3 solve f(x) > y in Z3Py throws an exception

Tags: python, z3

I am trying to execute the following solver:

```
solver = Solver()
f = z3.Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort())
y = z3.Int('y')
solver.add(f > y)
print(solver.check())
```

And I am getting the following exception:

> z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Python value cannot be used as a Z3 integer

on this line:

```
solver.add(f > y)
```

I am new to Z3, maybe I am understanding something wrong.

Comment: A function can't be compared to an integer, you need to apply the function to some arguments first.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I know that is legal to compare functions like "f == n" but it is some kind of restriction of the theory?

Comment: `f == n` is just as illegal as `f > y`; assuming `n` is an integer. Meta-question: What do you want `f > y` to mean if `f` is the function that returns its argument unchanged? Perhaps you're trying to say the function always produces a value that's greater than `y`, regardless of its argument? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

As Christoph mentioned, you cannot compare a function to a number, whether it's greater/less than, or equality. This really has nothing to do with z3. What would it mean as a mathematical statement?

Assuming what you're trying to say is that you want `f` to produce a value greater than `y` for any input it can receive, you can code it like this:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

f = Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort())
y = Int('y')
x = Int('x')
s.add(ForAll([x], f(x) > y))

if s.check() == sat:
    print(s.model())
else:
    print("not sat")
```

This prints the rather uninteresting model:

```
[y = 0, f = [else -> 1]]
```

which sets `y` to `0`, and `f` the constant function that always returns `1`; but at least it's type-correct.

Is this what you are after?

Comment: The arguments of the function are constants in my problem (at the moment I want to find if the system is sat or not). For example I want to find if it is sat { f(a,b,c) > n , f(a,b,c) > 0 } assuming both f(a,b,c) > n and f(a,b,c) > 0 are true.

Comment: Then you should declare the arguments (say `a`, `b`, `c`) as constants as well, and just compare `n` to the result of the call `f(a, b, c)`.

Comment: A top level declaration is always existentailly quantified. So, that'd act like your constant. You do not need quantifiers for this problem.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I'm not declaring a, b and c as Ints so I cannot simply add it to the solver as f(a,b,c) > y. Now I see the difference between the variables with universal quantifiers and without them.

Comment: z3's quantifier notation can be misleading: In the example I gave, there's a top-level declaration for `x`, but when it's used inside `ForAll` it acts only in that scope as a universal, not anywhere else. But that shouldn't be a problem for you since all you need are existentials, it seems. Feel free to ask a new question if you run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of my problem the function arguments are constants, so no universal quantifier is required. I also forgot to declare the constants used in the function and use them as arguments in the function.

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

f = Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort())
y = Int('y')
x = Int('x')
z = Int('z')
s.add(f(x,z) > y)

if s.check() == sat:
    print(s.model())
else:
    print("not sat")
```